# OpenCL modulo of large numbers

Tags: math, opencl, modulo

I'm trying to calculate `a mod b` in OpenCL, where `a` is an array of `ulong` elements, and is twice the length of `b`.

```
__kernel void mod(__global ulong *a, __global ulong *b, __global ulong length) {
    // length = len(a) = 2 * len(b)
    ...
}
```

What I want is something like `a %= b`, but with arrays. The arrays represent numbers of course, with their last element representing the least significant bits.

Is it possible to do this in-place (i.e. without allocating extra memory)? What is a good algorithm for calculating the medulus for large numbers?

Note that neither of the two numbers can be easily represented in another way (e.g. using exponents). Most of the times they will be pseudoprimes. Also, having some concurrency would be nice.

Pointers to any useful material on this are welcome.

**EDIT:** if that helps, `length` can be known at compile time.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry I wasn't clear here. I'm not working on an array of integers, I'm working on two big integers, for example `a` is 8Mb (*a **67108864-bit** number*) and `b` is 4Mb (*a **33554432-bit** number*). I work them in base 2^64, hence the arrays of `ulong` integers. Basically, those are just the digits of the number.

Comment: Do you intend that the divisors in the `b` array should each be used twice? That is, if `a` is [4,5,9,7] and `b` is [2,3] do you expect that after this that `a` should be [0,2,1,1] ?

Comment: @[Daniel Martin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/107331/daniel-martin) No, look at my final edit. I'm trying to work with arbitrary-length numbers.

Comment: Oh I see..... Maybe you should try with an algorithm to do that.

Comment: @[DarkZeros](http://stackoverflow.com/users/741692/darkzeros) good point. Do you know of any algorithms for modulo that I can run with OpenCL?

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread while googling because I am trying to do the same thing. Calculate n mod d where n and d are multi-limb unsigned integers. The code

```
a[id] = a[id] % b[id];
```

does element-wise modulo but that will not be the correct answer for multi-limb integers. A multi limb integer is an integer split into two or more limbs. The GMP library for instance handles this, as well as other bignum libraries. But I have not seen a working OpenCL implementation. If anybody knows of one, please reply. But I guess it would involve carry-over between limbs etc.

One use case would be for instance to search for prime factors on the GPU. But there are many other use cases too.

Comment: This comment was meant as a reply to the comment by DarkZeros. But it landed here for some reason.

Comment: Anyway, my idea is to try to implement mpz_div_qr() from the self-contained mini-gmp code: https://github.com/evdenis/mini-gmp/tree/master But OpenCL does not support malloc/free so the code would have to be rewritten with a hard-coded number of limbs.

Comment: I guess hard-coding that is not the end of the world here, even if you re-compile your code for every new input, it should be faster than a sequential algorithm using a single carry variable.

Answer (score 0):

You just do:

```
__kernel void mod(__global ulong *a, __global ulong *b, __global ulong length) {
   ulong id = get_global_id(0) ;
   a[id] = a[id] % b[id];
}
```

I don't really understand your problem, the arrays size difers? Or maybe you want a more special calculation?

Comment: I wanted to calculate modulo of arbitrarily large integers stored as arrays of `ulong`.